# Which way is the best way to convert from Sbyte[] to Byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I have been looking at a couple of ways to convert from sbyte[] to a byte[]

The most common approaches I have seen as follows

1.

```
sbyte[] signed = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 }; 
byte[] unsigned = (byte[]) (Array)signed;
```

2.

```
sbyte[] signed = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 }; 
byte[] unsigned = new byte[signed.Length]; 
Buffer.BlockCopy(signed, 0, unsigned, 0, signed.Length);
```

3.

```
byte[] dest = Array.ConvertAll(sbyteArray, (a) => (byte)a);
```

What are the pros and cons of these methods? To give you an example of what I am trying to accomplish. I receiving an image as a sbyte[] and would like to use the Image class to save the image to disk.

```
Image pic = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[]) ((Array) sbyteArr)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 is your best bet.  Even though it seems kinda "hacky", it's just a hack to make the compiler happy.  And this one will obviously be the fastest, because the data won't be copied.

I did a quick test, and the type conversion seems to work great.  Negative values are converted correctly, so it boils down to a simple type-coercion.